# Spring Transaction - Proxy confusion

Tags: java, spring, transactions

```
 <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="jtaTxManager">
  <tx:attributes>
   <tx:method name="*" />
  </tx:attributes>
 </tx:advice>

 <aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
  <aop:pointcut id="fooServiceOperation"
   expression="execution(* x.y.SampClass.save(..))" />
  <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="fooServiceOperation" />
 </aop:config>

 <bean id="Samp1" class=" x.y.SampClass"></bean>

        <bean id="SearchDispatchRpcGwtServlet" class="x.y.server.SearchDispatchRpcGwtServlet">
  <constructor-arg>
       <list>
         <ref bean="webServiceClient"/>                          
       </list>
  </constructor-arg>      
 </bean>

 <!-- Service Clients --> 
 <bean id="webServiceClient" class="x.y.KSBClientProxyFactoryBean">
  <property name="serviceEndpointInterface" value="x.y.service.WebService" />
  <property name="serviceQName" value="{http://x.y.org/wsdl/organization}WebService" />
 </bean>
```

This is the part of sample spring context file. I am trying to create a transaction advice for `SampClass` to execute on the save method.

So from my understanding it should create a proxy for `SampClass` only.

I have a `SearchDispatchRpcGwtServlet` which takes as an argument a webservice Client which is also a proxy in itself. This bean is also getting proxied for some reason where it fails because it cannot create a proxy of a proxy.

I must add that `SearchDispatchRpcGwtServlet` creates an instance of `SampClass` and calls the save method.

I get the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Cannot subclass final class class
>   $Proxy118 at
>   net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer
>   .java:446) at
>   net.sf.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.
>   generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)

I dont understand why `SearchDispatchRpcGwtServlet` proxy is getting created. Can someone explain.

Addition Stack Trace

```
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class $Proxy117]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class $Proxy117
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.getProxy(Cglib2AopProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:473)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:348)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:361)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1427)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport$1.run(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:139)
    ... 85 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class $Proxy117
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:446)
    at net.sf.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(Enhancer.java:285)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.getProxy(Cglib2AopProxy.java:201)
```

Comment: Can we see more of the stack trace? What you've given us isn't really enough.

Comment: I ll explain the issue in more detail.

I have an aop pointcut defined for Bean A. I have Bean B defined after Bean A in the context file. 
From what i imagine only Bean A proxy should be created. But in this case Bean B proxy is also created which contains a webserivce client proxy as an arguement. 

Is this a valid behaviour. Can i do something to avoid this. Meaning aop whould proxy  only the specified bean.

Comment: Still not enough... please don't truncate the stack trace at the point you think it stops being useful, add it all.

Comment: *"I must add that SearchDispatchRpcGwtServlet creates an instance of SampClass and calls the save method."* ... How is your service creating an instance of SampClass? Are you playing with bean scopes? That is a common cause for these proxying misconfigurations.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason not to use "<tx:annotation-driven/>" rather than defining the proxies manually? From your description I'd say you've got something else in your config causing the unexpected proxy to be created, eg something you haven't spotted is happening with the scoping and loading, like a servlet context. Can you reproduce the behaviour with a small test program?

Comment: Mixed proxying is the issue here. Try to set proxy-target-class="false" and make sure that save method is defined in an interface the service implements.

Answer (score 1):

a subclass of `AbstractAutoProxyCreator` is trying to proxy a bean, but that bean is already itself a CGLIB proxy created using another mechanism such as `aop:config proxy-target-class="true`.

To avoid this, make sure to avoid mixing the different aspect weaving mechanisms (ProxyBeanFactory and aop:config ) for the same bean.

In this case the transaction aspects can also be weaved via `<tx:annotation:driven/>` via the `@Transactional`  annotation.

Alternatively it would be possible to remove the autowiring/scan from the bean and do the injection of dependencies via XML using setters.

Another alternative is to use load time weaving everywhere by declaring `<context:load-time-weaver/>` and adding the needed jars.

Have a look also at this [post](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/aop/54520-mixing-jdk-and-cglib-proxies), it general it would be better to use only one one way of applying the aspects in the whole application, in order to avoid this problem.

Comment: Autowiring is not creating any proxy.

Comment: the `AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory` which according to the javadoc provides wiring (including autowiring) is trying to create a CGLIB proxy via a bean processor, it's in the stacktrace

Comment: No its not... a subclass of *AbstractAutoProxyCreator* is trying to create the proxy. This post processor is being probably registered by the AOP configuration. The fact that there is *AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory* on the stack trace is pretty irrelevant to the problem. Autowiring and component scan is unconnected set of features to proxying.