# Interceptor does not seem to work CrudRepository save method Spring Boot 2.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, interceptor

Trying an `interceptor` for logging purposes. Created a repository that extends `CrudRepository` with `Redis` Entity. I have simple `repository.save(entity)` method.

My interceptor looks like below:

```
public class MyRepoInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

  @Override
  public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, 
                      Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
     log.info("Saving...");
     return super.onSave(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onPrepareStatement(String sql)  {
     log.info("Prepared Statement");
     return super.onPrepareStatement(sql);
  }
}
```

I do not see the message `Saving...`, obviously interceptor is not working here.

However, in the same app, I have another repository for `mySQL`. In this, I have a repository method `findByXXX`. The interceptor is intercepting this method and I see the message `Prepared Statement`.

My interceptor Config class:

```
 @Component
 public class RepoInterceptor implements HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {

    @Autowired
    MyRepoInterceptor myRepoInterceptor;

    @Override
     public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
      //Tried this too. but no luck
      //hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.session_factory.interceptor", myRepoInterceptor); 
      hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.ejb.interceptor", myRepoInterceptor);
    }
 }
```

Has anyone tried this?
All that I want is, log any calls to database from "Crud/JPARepository" methods anywhere in the app without forcing the developer to do the logging.

If above is not the right solution, any other better solution(s)?

Comment: Try adding
 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ejb.interceptor=.com.repository.MyRepoInterceptor In application.properties.

Comment: Did that as well. No luck :-(

Comment: I'm confused. You're trying to make a Hibernate interceptor run for a Redis entity? How is that supposed to work? Spring Data does not use Hibernate for Redis, obviously. If you want to capture specific methods in repositories regardless of type, try [creating an aspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34332046/aspect-advice-for-spring-data-repository-doesnt-work) targeting the base `CrudRepository` interface

Comment: @crizzis You got me thinking! :-) I thought Redis as well uses Hibernate for operations. May be not? As for the Apsects, it does not have the information about the entity being operated on. So it won't work

Comment: Well, you can gain access to the invocation parameters inside an aspect, so you can get all the information from there. Not sure what your requirements are, though

Comment: What does it mean by ` gain access to the invocation parameters inside an aspect, so you can get all the information from there.`. Can you throw me an example / link?